# qt database result and connection

Tags: database, qt, connection, database-connection, qsqlquery

Good morning,
in my QT / C ++ project I have a class with name "**DataBase**" that opens a database giving a name to the connection like that:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(driver_db, "pippo");
```

In the same project in several parts I have to use the same database.
I thought about connecting to the database by calling the connection with its name

```
DataBase *database = new DataBase;
QSqlDatabase dbstructure = QSqlDatabase::database("pippo");
```

Although the connection is open and I do not have any error reports when I try to read a value of a selected record I do not return anything to the query.size () indicates me -1

```
        if(database->openDataBase(dbstructure)) {
        QSqlQuery querydb(dbstructure);
        QString strqrysearchprogram = "select * from nome_Tabella where Item  = '1'" ;
        if(querydb.exec(strqrysearchprogram)) {
            if (querygrare.first()) {
                qDebug() << querygrare.size();
                QString valuefield = querygrare.value("nameField").toString();
                qDebug() << "valuefield : " << valuefield;
                qDebug() << "qry: " << strqrysearchprogram;
            }
        } else {
            qDebug() << "record non trovato in qry: " << strqrysearchprogram;
        }
    } else {
        qDebug() << "ERROR open Database";
    }
```

Where am I wrong? Is it correct to recall the database with the name of the connection?
I state that I have checked the selection string that is passed and the record exists.

Comment: What `select * from *` return?

Comment: all field of the table

Comment: querygrare and querydb is different as I see? why did not you use querydb.first() ?

Comment: The wrong si different object. It's correct, into example, querydb

Comment: I'm new in this forum, where i marked solved question ?

Comment: The problem is solved.
Workaround:
to install the 64-bit Access Database Engine 2010 on a computer with 32-bit Microsoft Office 2007, 2010, or 2013.
Look this articles : How-to-install-64-bit-Microsoft-Database-Drivers-alongside-32-bit-Microsoft-Office ( link : https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-install-64-bit-Microsoft-Database-Drivers-alongside-32-bit-Microsoft-Office.html)